# How do I reliably determine if a `ControlTemplate` is being used in a WPF application?

Tags: .net, wpf, controltemplate

How do I reliably determine if the following `ControlTemplate` is being used in a WPF application? The file name is 'CheckBoxTemplates.xaml' and is in a different assembly than the main application. Note, there were no results when I searched for the file name and the resource key. In addition, searching the solution for a resource-key is not reliable. Especially, when there is five resource dictionary files that contain the same key.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:mwt="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Luna">
    <Style x:Key="invertedCheckBox"
           TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate  TargetType="CheckBox"
...
```

More Information

While user2250152 answser is correct for the above XAML. It does not reliably determine if a style is in use. I say this because, when I used the technique for another style, I found the five resource dictionary files that contain the same key. Therefore, we have to consider how do I determine reliably which style is used with defined with duplicate keys.

Comment: At runtime or compile time?

Comment: Either. The styles in the application are causing problems. The first step is to eliminate dead styles. I would be grateful for any way to do so. Even a separate tool would help.

Answer (score 3):

ReSharper shows dead code. Although its detection algorithm isn't perfect, it is a good start, allowing you to skip any style which it shows as used. For any style which is shown as unused, you can then check if it actually is unused (ex. by searching through the solution).

Comment: Does this work for xaml styles too? Couldn't find it.

Comment: I don't think ReSharper works. I purposely caused an unused style, and it gave no indication.

Comment: Detection algorithm isn't indeed perfect, the last I used it, it broke styles that were being used. Needless to say, they'll never get that perfect. As far as OP question goes, the answer is no, there is no reliable way :-). It's just not possible, simple as that. As Patrick said, the styles can be changed on runtime when events happen, when triggers happen, etc etc.. It's non-deterministic.

Comment: @Chris: true. The facade class may be the best option after all then.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options I can think of:

- The 'development time' solution: this includes searching every file for the existence of `Style="{StaticResource StyleName}"`, or something similar. This will work in a lot of cases, but isn't automated and not very reliable;
- The runtime solution: You could instantiate every control in the class library, and iterate over every element in it, checking the currently assigned `Style`. This only works for styles being set immediately, and not during events, etc.;
- The 'code' solution: You could create your own facade static class, that is an entry point to get a style. Note you are not allowed to use `Style="{StaticResource StyleName}"` any more, but `Style="{StaticResource SomeStaticClass.StyleName}"`. This will only work when you have a quality development team that is used to this working method. You can count the number of times a style is accessed over the duration of the program. If after a lot of time, the `Style` hasn't been used yet, it is probably candidate to get rid of.

Comment: Interesting. I did Item #1, but not reliable, hence the question. Item #3 is a good idea, but would it cover cases where the Style wasn't set explicitly? For Item #2, maybe Snoop can do this?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to use Snoop.

Comment: Okay. I am not that familiar with all the WPF tooling. I will take a look tomorrow when I am in the office.

Comment: Sorry. Stressy day in the office. Not much time to look in to this.

Comment: No problems. I can reliably delete this control-template due to the use of `x:Key`. user2250152 answer and some experimentation provided a reliable answer to this specific case. Yet, the problem still exists for other styles that are defined in multiple files.

Comment: It can be possible to add "attached property" into each `Style`. This attached property will be loaded once `Style` is loaded. This would help you to eliminate some of the styles that are loaded implicitly, and if necessary, explicit ones too.

Answer (score 2):

Unorthodox way of getting there would be to create an attached property which prints out who is using the ControlTemplate :) think about it like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:mwt="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Luna">
    <Style x:Key="invertedCheckBox"
           TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate  TargetType="CheckBox">
                 <Border my:WhoIsMyDaddy="true" ...>
```

`my:WhoIsMyDaddy` could be an attached property which triggers propertychanged event handler on initalizing when set to "`true`". Once handler called you will be able to access the instance of the control which is the owner of the attached property. In the end just print out whatever you want using that instance.

Comment: Interesting. The only downside is you would have to exercise ever check box control.

Comment: I would have to go to each screen that uses a `CheckBox` to use (exercise) every check box to see if the template is used. Correct?

Comment: No! If all of your checkboxes use the invertedCheckBox style they will all initalize the attached property. Every checkbox will have its own boolean attached property. When you set a breakpointer inside the handler, you will see when and which checkbox is attaching the dependency property to themself. That is how you will know if your controltemplate is being used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use VisualStudio and "Find in files" tool. Try to find style key, for example `invertedCheckBox` in entire solution. So you can determine where the style is used.

Comment: I have done this already and did not find the file name. I also searched for the 'key'. How do I know if a `CheckBox` is using this style? That is why I posted the questions. I need a reliable way.

Comment: Find all `CheckBoxes` in your solution. Check whether the `CheckBox` has style property sets to `Style="{StaticResource invertedCheckBox}"` If you find nothing then you can be sure that this style is not used.

Comment: I did that and found no uses. I then created a test project and did some testing. It seems that if `x:Key` is defined and not used, then the style is not used. There is no implicit use, because a key is always generated based on the `TargetType`.

Comment: Yes. Do you know something about implicit, explicit and default style?  <br/> Explicit style - the Style property is set directly. In most scenarios, the style is not defined inline, but instead is referenced as a resource, by explicit key.  <br/>Implicit style - the Style property is not set directly. However, the Style exists at some level in the resource lookup sequence (page, application) and is keyed using a resource key that matches the type the style is to be applied to.

Comment: Default style - also known as theme style. The Style property is not set directly, and in fact will read as null up until run time. In this case, the style comes from the run-time theme evaluation that is part of the WPF presentation engine. For implicit styles not in themes, the type must match exactly—a MyButton Button-derived class will not implicitly use a style for Button.

Comment: I understood, but I did not know that `x:Key` if not defined would be created from `TargetType`.

Comment: I still have to reliable determine if a style is in use when it is defined multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said

> The file name is 'CheckBoxTemplates.xaml' and is in a different assembly than the main application. Note, there were no results when I searched for the file name and the resource key.

you can be sure that this style is not used.
As far as I know there is no automatic loading of any XAML files (except for Application Resources and Themes)
Means there is no way any control could explicitly or implicitly reference this style (which seems to be unloaded- unless you have some code behind magic loading XAML files anyway)